# Hi team, how do i find the archetype for an existing project that was already build upon

Tags: maven, aem, archetypes

HI I am actually learning AEM(Adobe Experience manager) cms. I am working on an existing code base which was given to me, but i am unable to find the archetype that was build upon it.

Can someone pls point me how do i check on which archetype that the project was built upon??/

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason you are looking for the archetype?

Ideally archetype is not required once the project is generated, You can make use of it to update any dependencies required for future project upgrades and no need to generate the project again with the same/different archetype.

If you still want to look for the version, I don't think there is a direct way to find out the archetype version once it is created, you can check the release notes for the archetypes which shows the new changes/fixes they have done as part of the version.
https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype/tags
You should be able to compare them and find the respective version.

Most of the times, you can see the core component version changes and get the information right away.

**P.S** Again, even though you go through this process, you might not find the right version as someone in the team might have updated it for some requirements.

Let us know in specific if you are looking into any issue.